# Understanding why a complicated Entity Framework query returns null on a required relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Please help me understand the result of the following query.
I'm using Entity Framework 8 and PostgreSQL 15.4.

```cs
    var cart = await context.Carts
    .Where(c => c.Sessions.Contains(Instance.Session))
    .Include(c => c.Items)
        .ThenInclude(i => i.ProductPackage)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Product)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.Langs.Where(l => l.RegionID == Instance.Session.RegionID))
    .Include(c => c.Items)
        .ThenInclude(i => i.ProductPackage)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Product)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.Unit)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Langs.Where(l => l.RegionID == Instance.Session.RegionID))
    .Include(c => c.Items)
        .ThenInclude(i => i.ProductPackage)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Product)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.Images)
    .Include(c => c.Items)
        .ThenInclude(i => i.ProductPackage)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Product)
                .ThenInclude(p => p.ProductSlugs.Where(ps => ps.RegionID == Instance.Session.RegionID).OrderBy(ps => ps.Category == null ? int.MaxValue : ps.Category.Seq).Take(1))
    .Include(c => c.Items)
        .ThenInclude(i => i.ProductPackage)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.PriceLevels.Where(p => p.RegionID == Instance.Session.RegionID && p.RequiredPriceBand <= 1).OrderBy(pl => pl.QuantityMinimum))
    .Include(c => c.Items)
        .ThenInclude(i => i.ProductPackage)
            .ThenInclude(p => p.Langs.Where(p => p.RegionID == Instance.Session.RegionID))
    .AsSingleQuery()
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Which is translated into SQL like this:

```sql
SELECT t."ID", t5."ID", t5."CartID", t5."PackageQuantity", t5."ProductPackageID", t5."ID0", t5."Amount", t5."ProductID", t5."ID1", t5."Code", t5."ProductGroupID", t5."UnitID", t5."ID2", t5."ID3", t5."Description", t5."Name", t5."ProductID0", t5."RegionID", t5."YoutubeVideoLink", t5."ID4", t5."Abbreviation", t5."Name0", t5."PackagesTitle", t5."PriceLevelsTitle", t5."RegionID0", t5."UnitID0", t5."ID5", t5."Position", t5."ProductID1", t5."Url", t5."ID6", t5."CategoryID", t5."IsDeprecated", t5."ProductID2", t5."RegionID1", t5."Slug", t5."ID00", t5."ID7", t5."PackageID", t5."QuantityMinimum", t5."RegionID2", t5."RequiredPriceBand", t5."UnitPriceExcludingVatLocalCurrency", t5."ID8", t5."AmountLabel", t5."PackageLabel", t5."PriceLabel", t5."ProductPackageID0", t5."RegionID3"
FROM (
    SELECT c."ID"
    FROM "Carts" AS c
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM "Sessions" AS s
        WHERE c."ID" = s."CartID" AND s."ID" = @__entity_equality_Instance_Session_0_ID)
    LIMIT 1
) AS t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c0."ID", c0."CartID", c0."PackageQuantity", c0."ProductPackageID", p."ID" AS "ID0", p."Amount", p."ProductID", p0."ID" AS "ID1", p0."Code", p0."ProductGroupID", p0."UnitID", u."ID" AS "ID2", t0."ID" AS "ID3", t0."Description", t0."Name", t0."ProductID" AS "ProductID0", t0."RegionID", t0."YoutubeVideoLink", t1."ID" AS "ID4", t1."Abbreviation", t1."Name" AS "Name0", t1."PackagesTitle", t1."PriceLevelsTitle", t1."RegionID" AS "RegionID0", t1."UnitID" AS "UnitID0", p2."ID" AS "ID5", p2."Position", p2."ProductID" AS "ProductID1", p2."Url", t2."ID" AS "ID6", t2."CategoryID", t2."IsDeprecated", t2."ProductID" AS "ProductID2", t2."RegionID" AS "RegionID1", t2."Slug", t2."ID0" AS "ID00", t3."ID" AS "ID7", t3."PackageID", t3."QuantityMinimum", t3."RegionID" AS "RegionID2", t3."RequiredPriceBand", t3."UnitPriceExcludingVatLocalCurrency", t4."ID" AS "ID8", t4."AmountLabel", t4."PackageLabel", t4."PriceLabel", t4."ProductPackageID" AS "ProductPackageID0", t4."RegionID" AS "RegionID3", t2.c
    FROM "CartItems" AS c0
    INNER JOIN "ProductPackages" AS p ON c0."ProductPackageID" = p."ID"
    INNER JOIN "Products" AS p0 ON p."ProductID" = p0."ID"
    INNER JOIN "Units" AS u ON p0."UnitID" = u."ID"
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT p1."ID", p1."Description", p1."Name", p1."ProductID", p1."RegionID", p1."YoutubeVideoLink"
        FROM "ProductLang" AS p1
        WHERE p1."RegionID" = @__Instance_Session_RegionID_1
    ) AS t0 ON p0."ID" = t0."ProductID"
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT u0."ID", u0."Abbreviation", u0."Name", u0."PackagesTitle", u0."PriceLevelsTitle", u0."RegionID", u0."UnitID"
        FROM "UnitLang" AS u0
        WHERE u0."RegionID" = @__Instance_Session_RegionID_1
    ) AS t1 ON u."ID" = t1."UnitID"
    LEFT JOIN "ProductImages" AS p2 ON p0."ID" = p2."ProductID"
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT t6."ID", t6."CategoryID", t6."IsDeprecated", t6."ProductID", t6."RegionID", t6."Slug", t6."ID0", t6.c
        FROM (
            SELECT p3."ID", p3."CategoryID", p3."IsDeprecated", p3."ProductID", p3."RegionID", p3."Slug", c1."ID" AS "ID0", ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY p3."ProductID" ORDER BY CASE
                WHEN c1."ID" IS NULL THEN 2147483647
                ELSE c1."Seq"
            END) AS row, CASE
                WHEN c1."ID" IS NULL THEN 2147483647
                ELSE c1."Seq"
            END AS c
            FROM "ProductSlugs" AS p3
            LEFT JOIN "Categories" AS c1 ON p3."CategoryID" = c1."ID"
            WHERE p3."RegionID" = @__Instance_Session_RegionID_1
        ) AS t6
        WHERE t6.row <= 1
    ) AS t2 ON p0."ID" = t2."ProductID"
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT p4."ID", p4."PackageID", p4."QuantityMinimum", p4."RegionID", p4."RequiredPriceBand", p4."UnitPriceExcludingVatLocalCurrency"
        FROM "ProductPackagePriceLevel" AS p4
        WHERE p4."RegionID" = @__Instance_Session_RegionID_1 AND p4."RequiredPriceBand" <= 1
    ) AS t3 ON p."ID" = t3."PackageID"
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT p5."ID", p5."AmountLabel", p5."PackageLabel", p5."PriceLabel", p5."ProductPackageID", p5."RegionID"
        FROM "ProductPackageLang" AS p5
        WHERE p5."RegionID" = @__Instance_Session_RegionID_1
    ) AS t4 ON p."ID" = t4."ProductPackageID"
) AS t5 ON t."ID" = t5."CartID"
ORDER BY t."ID", t5."ID", t5."ID0", t5."ID1", t5."ID2", t5."ID3", t5."ID4", t5."ID5", t5."ProductID2", t5.c, t5."ID6", t5."ID00", t5."QuantityMinimum", t5."ID7"
```

When this query is running **concurrently with another query which deletes some of c.Items**, the query above is returns the following object:

[image: query result]

Note that:

- `CartItems` has a database foreign key targeting `Carts` and `ProductPackages`
- The transaction isolation level is `read committed` which [should ensure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/transaction-iso.html) that "single command sees an absolutely consistent view of the database"

Can you help me understand how a result of a single query can result in a partial information? How can `ProductPackageID` be filled, while `ProductPackage` is null? Is this a bug in PostgreSQL or Entity Framework?

My code which processes this query result assumes that `ProductPackage` is always present, as it's a non-nullable foreign key on `CartItem`, and thus crashes on Null Reference Exception. What is the proper resolution of this? Do I need to check nullability of all references om query results before access (even when they are required and not nullable)?

Comment: The non-nullable vs. nullable reference type is little more than a compiler warning/error when it detects an expected non-nullable reference not being provided a value. At runtime especially when reading data you should still check for null. It is strange that a product package ID was retrieved but the product package was #null. Read Committed affects the data read from the database however it may be possible that data is being pulled from the Context cache that is out of date. How is "When this query is running concurrently with another query which deletes some of c.Items," set up to execute?